invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference panic from delve package
Delve version:  1.23.1
Go version:  go1.23.2 darwin/arm64
Cursor version: 0.42.4 (VSCode 1.93.1)
OS: MacOS 14.6
Architecture:  M1 arm64
When running the debugger in VS Code, I get the following panic coming from delve.  It doesn't matter where I try to debug from, but it consistently happens.  It suddenly started happening while I was working.  Ive uninstalled, reinstalled, and updated both Go and Delve, but the problem persists.
error layer=dap recovered panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 34 [running]:
runtime/debug.Stack()
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.23.2/libexec/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:26 +0x64
github.com/go-delve/delve/service/dap.(*Session).recoverPanic(0x14000386000, {0x100bad4e0, 0x140026d97a0})
        /Users/me/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-delve/delve@v1.23.1/service/dap/server.go:579 +0x44
panic({0x100afb980?, 0x100f55550?})
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.23.2/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:785 +0x124
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/proc.fakeFunctionEntryScope(0x14000b280f0?, 0x100bb88b0?, 0x14000083720, 0x14000083718)
        /Users/me/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-delve/delve@v1.23.1/pkg/proc/fncall.go:979 +0x28
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/proc.funcCallStep(0x14000386500, 0x14002b190e0, {0x100bb88b0, 0x140026ec460})
        /Users/me/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-delve/delve@v1.23.1/pkg/proc/fncall.go:851 +0x408
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/proc.(*evalStack).resume(0x14002b190e0, 0x14002b56300)
        /Users/me/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-delve/delve@v1.23.1/pkg/proc/eval.go:925 +0x4b0
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/proc.callInjectionProtocol(0x14000b280f0, {0x140000cbd40?, 0x10097d150?, 0x0?})
        /Users/me/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-delve/delve@v1.23.1/pkg/proc/fncall.go:1094 +0x478
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/proc.(*TargetGroup).Continue(0x14000124140)
        /Users/me/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-delve/delve@v1.23.1/pkg/proc/target_exec.go:162 +0x870
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/proc.EvalExpressionWithCalls(0x14000124140, 0x14003f9c240, {0x1400337a870, 0x29}, {0x1, 0x1, 0x400, 0x40, 0xffffffffffffffff, 0x0}, ...)
        /Users/me/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-delve/delve@v1.23.1/pkg/proc/fncall.go:190 +0x3d4


if devle is panicking using current releases of everything, then you should open an issue with delve.

Looks like OP raised this issue but may not have seen this issue (comments indicate the panic was probably due to a watch expression in that case).

@Brits thanks, and yes I did not see that.  I removed the watch expression and all works now

As Brits pointed out, removing my watch expressions fixed it. See https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/3700
